# How do I change the Kendo alert title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, alert, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using a Kendo alert and want to change the title of it. The default title is the url name, see link(image) below. I want to use my own title, how do I change this?

[Image Kendo alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AscDa.png)

The kendo alert:

```
kendo.alert("mytext");
```

Comment: use css hide title

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I already found a solution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution to change the title, I did the following:

```
myalert("mytext"); 

function myalert(content) {
    $("<div></div>").kendoAlert({
        title: "mytitle!",
        content: content
    }).data("kendoAlert").open();
}
```

Result:
[Image Kendo alert custom title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX8Hd.png)

I hope this answer helps a lot of people with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me to also set a few other properties while keeping the convenience of predefined kendo "alert" method.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot change the Title it's possible to hide it using css:

```
.k-dialog .k-window-titlebar .k-dialog-title {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kendo Alert inherits from Kendo Dialog, you can update the title with the [`title()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dialog/methods/title) method:

```
kendo.alert("Hello!").element.getKendoAlert().title("new title");
```

https://dojo.telerik.com/EGOKeQAl

You can chain the [`center()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dialog/methods/center) method if the alert is not centered after the title change.

```
kendo.alert("Hello!").element.getKendoAlert().title("new title").center();
```